# Unable to create Genymotion virtual device: HTTP error response: Unknown error

Tags: android, genymotion

I'm receiving an error while I try to add a virtual device using Genymotion.

Unable to create Genymotion virtual device.
HTTP error response: Unknown error.

I've tried checking my network access and rebooting it. But still getting the same error.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Thank you.
Sowmya.

Comment: Try running with Administrative privileges and then create it.

Comment: @JoelFernandes Still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Could you paste the log entries? Check the genymotion.log file- https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/faq/#collapse-logs

Comment: I ran the "Virtual Box Manager" before running Genymotion and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea that helped me:

```
1.- Unplug your LAN cable (if any), connect to Wi-Fi network
2.- Retry to sign in to Genymotion using your Wi-Fi network
```

In my case that solved the issue