# Cannot create a Virtual Device with GenyMotion

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I'm trying to create a virtual device with GenyMotion in Ubuntu 14.04. I have installed VirtualBox & registered on GenyMotion. When I log in on the app and select Nexus 5 device, I get the following error:

[image]

I found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216697/unable-to-create-genymotion-virtual-device-http-error-response-unknown-error), but it didn't solve my problem.

In that post, they ask you to run "Virtual Box Manager", I did that too but still keep getting that error.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Downloading a virtual device from within genymotion is painful, it not only gives HTTP error you are facing but many other different errors for different people.

To begin, Remove all virtual box and genymotion installations, and
delete all files from genymotion folder, specially from ova folder present inside genymotion folder.

1. Download virtual device from an external source. { There are many links on web, where people have put up their virtual device on google drive where you can download from}
2. Install genymotion.
3. Place this virtual device inside ova folder. {On windows, it is present inside genymotion folder}
4. Create virtual device from inside genymotion, and choose same version of device which you had downloaded in step 1.
5. Genymotion automatically detects the virtual device and doesn't download again.
6. If you face some error, start virtual device from within virtual box 2-3 times {it gives error too, but after each error you don't get error at same point} & then open it from genymotion.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, got a fix. I used my own Android SDK in settings and used Samsung Galaxy S4 on Android 4.3 and it's working fine now.

Maybe the SDK was the problem.